# SQL Calculate weekly active users by device resolution

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calculate my apps weekly active users by device resolution.

I got dailyData table that looks like that:

- **raw_advertiser_id** unique user id
- **screen_dimensions** screen resolution information string
- **day_id** an integer that counts how many days past from April 2017

It's unique on **raw_advertiser_id** and **day_id**

Here is a result of weekly active users by resolution for users who installed my app on April 25 2017, using PostgresSQL

```
WITH users AS (
    SELECT raw_advertiser_id
    FROM beep.dailydata
    WHERE day_id < 25 + 7
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING min(day_id) = 25
)

SELECT
  screen_dimensions,
  count(DISTINCT raw_advertiser_id) totalUsers,
  count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN day_id > 25
    THEN raw_advertiser_id END) weeklyActiveUsersCount,
  round(count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN day_id > 25
    THEN raw_advertiser_id END) :: NUMERIC / count(DISTINCT raw_advertiser_id) * 100,2) weeklyActiveUsersPercent
FROM beep.dailydata
  JOIN users USING (raw_advertiser_id)
  WHERE day_id < 25 + 7
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY totalUsers DESC
```

Result:

resolution, totalUsers, weeklyActiveUsers, weeklyActiveUsersPercent

```
720x1280x2.00   10  2   20
320x1152x1.00   8   0   0
480x800x1.00    5   0   0
720x1280x0.00   3   1   33.33
480x854x1.00    3   0   0
720x1184x2.00   2   0   0
```

I would like to perform this query not only on April 25 but on all the next days as well and merge the result. In the above query to get the result of April 26, you simply need to replace the number 25 with 26. The question is how do I do this in a query?

Comment: Can you show as well how you want to merge result using an example ?

Comment: @FahadAnjum just sum the totalUsers and weeklyActiveUsers and recalculate the weeklyActiveUsersPercent